# malloc and realloc size of integer array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I want to be able to realloc the amount of space as my program reads in numbers.
For example when running it should be able to read any number of integer and then print them out as 'Int Array: (all inputs)'
This is what I have tried so far:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0, n, num;
    int *A;

    A = malloc(sizeof(A));

    while(scanf("%d",&num) == 1)
    {
        A[i] = num;
        i++;
    }

    n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);

    printf("Int Array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int A*` is not valid!

Comment: Also, `sizeof A` gives you 4 or 8 usually, i.e. the size of the pointer, not the size of the data it points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also first reserve a specific amount of memory i.e:
If the user inputs more than 10 items you realloc another block of memory of say 20 integers and copy the last 10 items into the new block and so on.

```
size_t block_length = 10;
size_t current_length = 0;
int *A = malloc(sizeof(int) * block_length); // to store 10 integer
if (A == NULL)
    doNotContinue_AllocationFailure();
current_length += block_length;
// ... input the first ten numbers, check if count numbers is lesser
// than block_length
void *ptr;
ptr = realloc(A, sizeof(int) * (block_length + current_length)
if (ptr == NULL)
 {
    free(A); /* Otherwise a memory leak occurs */
    doNotContinue_AllocationFailure();
 }
A = ptr;

// A can now hold up to 20 numbers, and you can input the next 10 numbers
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code has some problems

1. The syntax `int A*;` is not valid, you mean `int *A;`
2. If you want to allocate one element the right syntax is

   ```
   A = malloc(sizeof(*A));
   ```
3. In this line

   ```
   n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
   ```

   The `sizeof()` operator gives the size of the type which is a poitner, in this case it's the same as

   ```
   n = sizeof(void *) / sizeof(int);
   ```

   which can be `2` or `1`.

You can set the size of the array statically in which case I would recommend avoiding `malloc()`, or you can ask the user, in any case you cannot obtain that size from the pointer so you must store it, example

```
if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1)
    return -1;

A = malloc(size * sizeof(*A));
if (A == NULL)
    return -1;
/* proceed to work with `A' and keep `size' somewhere, you need it */
free(A);
```

Comment: oh ok so its impossible to alter the size as the user inputs? So you would have to ask the user or set a size beforehand?

Comment: and also if i was to set a size beforehand how would I use realloc to constrain it down to the numbers of elements the user has inputted. So I could print out each int e.g.(for (i = 0; i < n; i++))

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to reallocate memory in every new input.

```
 int indefiniteInput() {

    int num;
    int index = 0;
    int *inputs = malloc(sizeof (int));

    if (inputs == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed!");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Input numbers: ");

    while(scanf("%d", &num) == 1) {

        // stops getting inputs when -1 is entered, 
        // you can change it to any value you want
        if (num == -1)
            break;

        // reallocates memory for the input
        int *temp = realloc(inputs, sizeof (int) * (index + 1));

        if (temp == NULL) {
            free(inputs);
            perror("realloc failed!");
            return -1;
        }

        inputs = temp;  

        // adds the last input to reallocated memory
        inputs[index++] = num;
    }

    printf("Stored inputs: ");

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < index; i++)
        printf("%d ", inputs[i]);

    free(inputs);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input numbers: 5 6 7 8 9 -1
Stored inputs: 5 6 7 8 9 -1

Input numbers: 1 2 3 5 -5 -6 89 256 2001 45600 96 33 369 -1
Stored inputs: 1 2 3 5 -5 -6 89 256 2001 45600 96 33 369
```

Comment: Do not use `realloc()` like that! And always think that the worse will happen so you prevent not being prevented, as with `malloc()` which might return `NULL`.